# How to see size of voice channels that my bot is currently in (joined)?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How could I add the current size of voice channel connections to my `/info` command? I tried using `console.log` and logging `client.voice.adapters`, but still didn't manage to figure it out.
I know that this is a simple question, but maybe answers from you guys will help others, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't manage to find an answer to my question, but I came up with a solution. I found a way that works for me and is easier than looking for code chunks or asking questions.

- Here's a tip: If you make silly mistakes as I did, check the docs.
  In this case ( [Discord.js.org](https://discord.js.org/#/) and [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) ).

---

**What did I do / how to?**

1. Create a `new Map();`
2. Use `<Map>.set` and `<Map>.delete` to add and remove a number.
3. Use `else if(newState.status === "idle") { 4th step }` to check if the new state status is equal to Idle.
4. Add the `<Map>.delete(interaction.guild.name, <numberToRemove>);` function into 3th step function to remove one number from the map.

---

**Copy and Paste if you are too lazy:**

> Function for adding a number to map should look like this: `<MapName>.set(interaction.guild.name, <numberToAdd>);`
> Function for deleting a number from map looks like this: `<MapName>.delete(interaction.guild.name, <numberToRemove>);`

Answer (score 1):

[`client.voice.adapters`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientVoiceManager?scrollTo=adapters) maps guild ids to voice adapters. It returns a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and `Map`s have a [`size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/size) property that returns the number of elements in that `Map`.

Would this work?

```js
client.voice.adapters.size
```

Comment: I had tried it before, It returns an Empty map with a size: 0
I'll try to play with properties and if I will get an answer I will post it, thanks for the edit and response @Zsolt Meszaros